# Subset a matrix in R by rowname and colname

Tags: r

I have a matrix with columns and rows which I am trying to subset but I getting and stranger error that I cannot understand.

Columns represent years while rows represent the age of males.

When I execute the code bellow I was expecting to get a matrix with rows between 50 and 90 and columns between 1961 and 2013.

```
Death_male = Death$Male.Matrix[(rownames(Death$Male.Matrix) >= 50) & (rownames(Death$Male.Matrix) <= 90), 
                               (colnames(Death$Male.Matrix) >= 1961) & (colnames(Death$Male.Matrix) <= 2013)]
```

But in my output it also shows rows for ages between 6 and 9. See bellow an example, where I have omitted part of the columns and rows.

```
      1961    1962 1963 1964 1965 1966 1967  1968  1969  1970
6   212.61  194.28  223  196  230  203  212   230   192   241
7   191.69  192.03  205  187  202  164  185   196   214   208
8   159.49  153.56  182  163  183  193  193   153   167   149
9   173.98  152.85  175  161  170  169  165   192   148   162
50 2643.29 2632.89 2791 2656 2599 2484 2212  1965  2169  2936
51 2980.60 3018.17 2924 2841 2992 2804 2519  2504  2254  2350
52 3412.15 3395.82 3415 3329 3292 3351 3063  2997  2753  2462
53 3821.95 3751.85 3742 3645 3616 3725 3445  3547  3336  3126
54 4050.00 4101.27 4220 4094 4183 4029 3832  3898  4020  3654
55 4400.87 4508.00 4607 4454 4412 4330 4139  4290  4404  4491
```

What is erro that is making rows between 6 and 9 appear? I cannot figure it out

Comment: `rownames` are character strings. You need to convert them using `as.numeric` otherwise the logical test is checking lexicographic ordering, where `6` is greater than `50` (i.e. it would come after 50 in the dictionary)

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Allan Cameron, rownames are character strings. I should convert them to numeric to do the logical test I want to perform